# Vacation calendar in Excel with restrictions

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar, restrictions

I am trying to make a vacation calendar in Excel that will prevent a user from entering more than the allowed number of people off per department per day.

I have a workbook that lists all employees and assigns them a department code letter, and the date on the calendar will auto-populate with the department code when they are marked off for that day. I need each day on the calendar to restrict the number of people off in each department. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done regarding this?

Comment: I have no idea where to even start doing this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to need lookup or reference tables. One at least that has the department codes and a "max allowed on leave" value for each. Then you can write a formula that counts the number of people off and indicates when this matches of exceeds the value in that lookup table for the department.

Comment: @Lburg23 please add information about what you already have, like an example table showing how you've formatted your calendar? You probably want to use data validation (like a dropdown), and make the source be a filtered table of valid department codes like the writeup here: https://www.contextures.com/exceldropdownfilteredlist.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never used this site before, I don't know how to attach the workbook so you can look at it. It's basically a worksheet for every month with 80 employees. I have a reference table that assigns each employee a letter for their department and the monthly worksheet will populate any cell that is color coded for an off day with that department code. I have another reference table that counts the number of each letter code under each day. I am not sure how to connect the pieces of information to prevent more than the allowed number to be marked off per day.

Comment: You'll need VBA to restrict/prevent. If you are happy with some type of error display, then use data validation or conditional formatting.

Comment: You can't attach whole workbooks to a question.  You can use [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) to format data into a table so it can be pasted into your question.  We can then copy that data and paste it into our own workbooks.